# How to call a component function from different file (no class/component) in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

)

I am programming a Notes App. The Note is saved when navigating back to the homescreen (away from Note Edit Component). The List of the Notes Titles (in HomeScreen) is updated onWillFocus. The Problem is the note save is async and takes some time... so onWillFocus updates the list BEFORE the note is saved. Now i want to call the list update manually when the note save resolves. But I have no idea how to do that.

I have one db file where all database functions live in. And two components. 
Now i need to call a function in the HomeScreen Component from the db file.

that is my db file (removed other functions)

```
//db imports and making a const db

export function updateNote(updateStuff) {
  db.get(_id).then(function(doc) {
    return db.put({
      //updateStuff
    });
  }).then(async function(response) {
    console.log(response)
    //here i need to call the function
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

and this is my HomeScreen Component

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  //all elements
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

import { putNote, getAllNotes, deleteAllNotes } from './db/db.js';

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    notes: [],
  }

  async renderAllNotes() {
    let result = await getAllNotes();
    this.setState({notes: result.rows});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <NavigationEvents
          onWillFocus={() => this.renderAllNotes()}
        />

      <FlatList

         //Flat List Code

        /> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my Note Edit component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  //stuff
} from 'react-native';


import { updateNote, getNote, getAllNotes } from './db/db.js';

export default class NoteScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    _id: this.props.navigation.getParam('_id'), 
  }

  updateThisNote() {
    updateNote(this.state._id, this.state.title, this.state.content, this.state.createdAt);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.updateThisNote();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ title: text })}
          value={this.state.title}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ content: text })}
          value={this.state.content}
        />

        <Button
          title='update Note'
          onPress={() => this.updateThisNote()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and now renderAllNotes should be calln when updateNote resolves.

I already tried importing the HomeScreen class in the db file and calling the function as well as trying to export the render allNotes function an import it in the db file. Without success ;(

Thank you for every help ;)

EDIT:

```
async putNoteAndPushRoute() {
    let resolve = await putNote("");
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Note', {
      _id: resolve.id,
      renderAllNotes: this.renderAllNotes.bind(this),
    });
  }
```

Error Message: _this2.props.renderAllNotes is not a function

Comment: From where do you call updateNote()?

Comment: It's a no-op to call a component method from another file in order to achieve that. Consider either passing down the props to this component or use a state management architecture like redux https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Can you also post your edit component

Comment: I call update Note in the willUnmount lifecycle hook from the Note Edit component when navigating back to the homescreen (stack layout). How can i pass down a prop? @joelgullander

Comment: wait a second @Sarmad

Comment: If you call that when on unmount and you don't use redux or any other state management tools you should not fetch the data from the leaving component, you should call a function from a parent when unmounting so that component can wait for the data to return and then pass it down to the components that needs to consume it.

Comment: like: componentWillUnmount() { this.props.mockFunc() }

Comment: the note update is handled in the onUnmount but the render all Notes function which updates the list is in the same component. The problem is that it is calln to early (by the event listener onWillFocus) so it updates the list even the note has not been saved. @joelgullander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `this.renderAllNotes()` to your edit component.

Like this.

```
...
renderAllNotes(){
      ....
  }
...
render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
         <View>
            <Button onPress={() =>{
                  navigate('Edit',{
                      renderAllNotes: this.renderAllNotes.bind(this)
                  });
            }} />
         </View>
    )
}
```

...

And then inside your edit, 
you can just call the renderAllNotes after the note is updated. But you need to change your updateNote to return a promise

```
 updateThisNote(){
// Make sure your updateNote returns a promise
        updateNote(this.state._id, this.state.title, 
 this.state.content, this.state.createdAt)
.then(() => {
const { params} = this.props.navigation.state;
params.renderAllNotes();
});
 }

 componentWillUnmount() {
    this.updateThisNote();
 }
```

you can change your update function to return a promise

```
export function updateNote(updateStuff) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  db.get(_id).then(function(doc) {
    return db.put({
      //updateStuff
    });
  }).then(async function(response) {
    console.log(response)
     //resolve it here
     resolve();
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
   }
}
```

This would solve your issue.

Comment: thank you very much i will try it out as soon as possible ;) @Sarmad

Comment: this code is unreadable. This solution should work..make sure you are doing everything right. And you can update your question with this code or something

Comment: try to access the function with this.props.navigation.getParam("renderAllNotes"'),
for example this.renderAllNotes = this.props.navigation.getParam('renderAllNotes');
and then using this.renderAllNotes();
if this doesnt work, try to console.log your navigation object...it should be there somewhere :), i updated my answer too, updatethisnote function...do check it

Comment: wuhu this fixed it ;) Thank you very much @Sarmad

Comment: welcome, you can approve or vote my answer too :) thanks